# How to add raw text (non-source) files to an Xcode project?

Tags: xcode

I'm trying to add a JSON file to a folder inside my Xcode project. When I right-click my folder and select **New File**, I get this window:

[image: New file window]

However, it won't allow me to add a raw text file (such as `myconfig.json`, etc.). **So how do I create JSON and other raw text/non-iOS (Swift, etc.) source files in my project in Xcode?**

Comment: For me, it is possible to scroll down in the big area where you select file type. At the bottom there is a section named “Other” with an ”Empty” file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just **drag** any separately created file(s) you want on **Navigator** (on the left side on your window) and select **Copy items if needed** when the popup shows up.

[image: Adding files - Selected Copy items if needed]

If the Navigator is not visible, click on the **Hide or show the Navigator** button in the top-right corner (the first button in the second group).

[image: "Hide or show the Navigator" button]

As [@Mats](https://stackoverflow.com/users/909655/mats) mentioned, it's also possible to select **Other/Empty** from the **New File** popup and specify the extension later.

[image: Other/Empty in New File]